# React - on outside click of component subtree

Tags: reactjs

I'm aware of several solutions to detecting 'outside' clicks from a React component - i.e. those that basically use the DOM elements' `.contains` method to see if an event originated within the DOM tree - however, does anyone know of any that can detect such events 'outside' of the actual component hierarchy? For example, this would work with portals where the above method would not (since the DOM tree isn't representative of the React tree).

EDIT: Example:

```
<div>
  <div onOutsideClick={handleOutsideClick}> // onOutsideClick implementation todo
    <div>
      <button /> // same dom tree, same component tree, would be detected as NOT outside (ding)
    </div>
    <div>
      <Portal>
        <button /> // NOT same dom tree, but same component tree, would be detected as outside (bzzt)
      </Portal>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button /> // not same component tree, nor dom tree, would be detected as outside (ding)
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't listening to `click` in `window` good enough?

Comment: I don't think that achieves what I'm after, or not on it's own. As I mentioned, I'm aware that 'outside click' detectors do this, but once they detect the click they still have to answer the question of 'was this outside of X', but they do so using the DOM tree, not the React component tree. Again, portals are where this approach would not suffice.

Comment: I've used this component in the past and it was helpful https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-click-outside

Comment: @Fotis - thanks, but it looks like that also uses the DOM to determine if a click is 'outside' rather than the component tree, so it wouldn't work for this case.

Comment: @Barguast i'm in the same spot, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @tommyalvarez - I came up with a solution. It's been working for me, but it's ugly. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/jamiewinder/26e0ef41aa04b6d038c4c633f26d275c. The idea is basically that you attach the equivalent event on the `window` object and if it reaches that, check whether it went through your component. Unfortunately it means combining DOM and React events.